# Использование объекта в контроллере ASP NET MVC без его пересоздания

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть код:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    UpdateService updService = new UpdateService();
    public void CheckUpdates(string [] codes)
    {
        updService.CheckUpdates(codes);
    }

}
```

Проблема в том, что каждый раз при вызове CheckUpdates() происходит пересоздание объекта UpdService, чего нужно избежать. Как выйти из данной ситуации?

Comment: какая версия mvc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного удивлен, что никто не упоминает возможные проблемы использования одного объекта `UpdateService` из разных потоков - особенно в контексте веб-приложения, многопоточного по своей природе. Первый вопрос в такой ситуации - является ли `UpdateService` потоко-безопасным (thread-safe). Если на этот вопрос нет однозначно-положительного ответа, то обращения к синглтону придется оборачивать в `lock`, что отрицательно скажется на скорости обработки запросов.

Вы не написали, чем вызвано желание иметь только один `UpdateService`. Может быть в коде просто не хватает освобождения ресурсов, используемых внутри этого класса:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public void CheckUpdates(string [] codes)
  {
    using(UpdateService updateService = new UpdateService())
    {
      updateService.CheckUpdates(codes);
    }
  }
}
```

или

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  UpdateService updateService = new UpdateService();

  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing)
    {
      updateService.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
  }

  public void CheckUpdates(string [] codes)
  {
    updateService.CheckUpdates(codes);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Объявить как статический член класса. Тогда объект будет создан
  только один раз на все время выполнения программы, при ее запуске.

  static UpdateService updService = new UpdateService();
- Если Вы используете `Ninject`, то использовать метод
  `ToSingletonScope()`

  kernel.Bind().To().ToSingletonScope(); где `Т` - интерфейс/класс для которого вы регистрируете.

  > `InSingletonScope()` - создает одиночный экземпляр, который разделяется
  >   по всему приложению. Ядро `Ninject` будет создавать экземпляр, если
  >   используется метод `InSingletonScope()`, или же экземпляр можно
  >   предоставить посредством метода `ToConstant()`

Про внедрение зависимостей можно посмотреть [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level2/2_3.php)

Comment: т.е. он не будет создаваться снова при каждом запросе?а будет привязан к времени жизни приложения(сайта)?

Comment: @MaratBatalandabad Да.

Comment: "при ее запуске" - при выполнении статического конструктора класса, содержащего это поле.

Comment: @Igor а когда выполняются все статические конструкторы? При запуске.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk - при первом обращении https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Comment: @Igor Да, был не прав. Но в контексте данной задачи это не имеет значет

Answer (score -2):

Как альтернативу использованию статических членов класса могу предложить испльзовать паттерн Singlton для реализации класса `UpdateService`

```
public class UpdateService
{
    private static UpdateService instance;

    private UpdateService() { }

    public static UpdateService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new UpdateService();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    UpdateService updService = UpdateService.Instance;
    public void CheckUpdates(string[] codes)
    {
        updService.CheckUpdates(codes);
    }

}
```

Comment: Singleton да, но только средствами IoC-контейнера, но никак не предложенным способом.

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, могли бы вы более подробно объяснить недостатки данного способа в сравнении с  использованием статического члена класса ?

Comment: @koks_rs по сравнению со статическим членом класса - никаких. По сравнению с использованием IoC (как предложил  Primus Singularis) - на ваш вариант  HomeController нельзя написать юнит-тест. А на вариант с IoC - можно.